# ruby list ancestors which are not mixins

Tags: ruby, inheritance

Best explained in code....

```
>> String.ancestors
=> [String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
>> Comparable.ancestors
=> [Comparable]
>> Object.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
>> Kernel.ancestors
=> [Kernel]
>> BasicObject.ancestors
=> [BasicObject]
```

So I suspect the inheritance chain is String < Object < BasicObject... and Comparable and Kernel are mixins...

Is there a function 'foobar' which can show the inheritance:

```
>> String.foobar
=> [Object, BasicObject]
```

*And if possible with the hidden metaclasses storing the singleton methods be included as well?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String.ancestors.grep(Class)
```

......................

Comment: This is basically how [`Class.superclass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Class.html#method-i-superclass) works - traversing the ancestors and checking each ancestor's type.

Comment: Yep. Within the YARV sourcecode, those classes that are skipped in the class ancestry are called "virtual classes", and they are the singleton classes and the "include classes" (classes which are generated and injected into the inheritance chain when including a mixin).

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
class Class
  def foobar
    ancestors - included_modules - [self]
  end
end
```

Comment: `foobar` should be a method of `Class` (modules can't have non-module ancestors)